# HTTP GET Request from Power Automate to AWS Lambda HTTP Endpoint Fails

Tags: python, http, aws-lambda, power-automate

I have a simple AWS Lambda function created using Python. I have created an HTTP Endpoint URL to call the function which requires no authentication.
I get a proper response if I call the HTTP Endpoint URL using Request library in Python.
But I am trying to create a Microsoft Power Automate flow that can invoke the Lambda function using its HTTP Endpoint URL.

The lambda_handler simply returns the following:

```
return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': 'Hello World from AWS'
        }
```

When I run an HTTP Flow with a GET request to lambda function url, I get an error message as  below:

**Http request failed: the content was not a valid JSON. Error while parsing JSON: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: H. Path '', line 0, position 0.'**

I have attached an image of the flow configuration.

[image: HTTP Flow Configuration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to return a valid JSON from your Lambda.

`'Hello World from AWS'` is just a string, and the error tells you that `H` is an unexpected JSON symbol.

You have to wrap your response into `json.dumps` function:

Change your code to:

```py
import json

return {
  'statusCode': 200,
  'body': json.dumps('Hello World from AWS')
}
```